# Weview doesn't shirnk when keyboard is appeared on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-webview

**Problem**: The height of webview doesn't reduce when I open up the keyborad on IOS

I used a `KeyboardAvoidingView` wrap my `Webview` like this

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
  style={isKeyboardOpen ? {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
  position: 'absolute',
  left: webViewConfig.x,
  top: webViewConfig.show ? y : deviceHeight,
  width: deviceWidth - webViewConfig.x,
  height: deviceHeight - y - keyboardHeight,
  } : {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
  position: 'absolute',
  left: webViewConfig.x,
  top: webViewConfig.show ? y : deviceHeight,
  width: deviceWidth - webViewConfig.x,
  height:
  deviceHeight - y
  }}
>
  // webivew here
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I even make the height of `KeyboardAvoidingView` is dynamically change when the keyboard is hidden/appeared.

Please check the image below. I'd like to make the red section is dissapeared. Or at least make the content of webview fit into the container's space (which is `KeyboardAvoidingView` component) and make it unable to scroll down.

**Screenshots/Videos:**

[image: Image from iOS]

I add `style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}` into Weview. As you can see that the webview's content is shirnked as exepected but the red bacground still appear.

**Environment:**

- OS: IOS
- OS version: 15.4.1
- react-native version:  0.64.2
- react-native-webview version: 11.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case. I need to prevent the webview from scrolling. There is a property called `scrollEnabled` of the `WebView` component that does that. The codes will look like this

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
  style={{
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
  position: 'absolute',
  left: webViewConfig.x,
  top: webViewConfig.show ? y : deviceHeight,
  width: deviceWidth - webViewConfig.x,
  height: deviceHeight - y
  }}
>
  <Webview 
    // other properties 
    scrollEnabled={false} // -> set this to false
  />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```